# Unity disable notifications to appear while the application is running

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, notifications

As the title says, I'm scheduling some notifications for android on unity but I would like them to not appear if the app is open (only foreground and closed). I didn't find any information on the documentation. I guess I can cancel them right before the fire time, but is there any other option?